# Symfony 4 user search by email issues

Tags: php, symfony, twig, php-7, symfony4

I am trying to implement a search for user by email function into page admin's dashboard. Currently, I have hardcoded a value into `$email` variable just to test whether the search works. It does find the right user, but does not display anything in the twig.

Executing {{ dump() }} outputs: array:2 [▼ 0 => User {#4745 ▼ -id: 5 - 
   username: "test_user" -plainPassword: null -password: 
   "$2y$13$rGYteIrzifg9Dty.O5knOOCHQnzOtF.nZux8h1jc4sNbap5V7Xn0." -email: 
   "tester@test.com" } "app" => AppVariable {#2617 ▶} ]

the function I use in AdminController.php:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/result", name="user_search")
 * Method({"POST"}) 
 */       
    public function user_search(Request $request)
    {
        $email = 'tester@test.com';

        $result = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

        if ($result) {

        return $this->render('admin/result.html.twig',  $result);    

        }else{

        return $this->render('admin/result.html.twig', [
            'error' => 'No user found with this email '.$email]);

    }}
```

result.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

{% if error %}
        <span class="error">{{ error }}</span>
{% endif %}

{% if result %}
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Username</th><th>Email</th>
                </tr>
                {% for item in result %}

                    <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.getUsername }}</td><td>{{ item.getEmail }} 
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </table>
            {% endif %}
            {{ dump() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try with {% if result is defined %}

Comment: @D.Dimitrov Thank you, this solves one part of the issue. Now I get the twig rendered, but, apparently, the $result is always undefined.

Comment: Could you please edit or post what does {{ dump() }} output in your twig file?

Comment: @D.Dimitrov the output of dump() is:

 array:2 [▼
  "error" => "No user found with this email test@tester.com"
  "app" => AppVariable {#2617 ▶}
]

Comment: If you've enabled debug mode, could you see what exactly queries are prepared to the database? Or any errors you got?

Comment: @D.Dimitrov sorry, I had a typo in the $email variable. It does find the right user, but does not display anything in the twig. array:2 [▼
  0 => User {#4745 ▼
    -id: 5
    -username: "test_user"
    -plainPassword: null
    -password: "$2y$13$rGYteIrzifg9Dty.O5knOOCHQnzOtF.nZux8h1jc4sNbap5V7Xn0."
    -email: "tester@test.com"
  }
  "app" => AppVariable {#2617 ▶}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was finally solved by these steps:

1. There was a typo in the hardcoded `$email` variable.
2. Changed `return $this->render('admin/result.html.twig',  'result'->$result);` instead of `return $this->render('admin/result.html.twig',  $result);`
3. Changed `<td>{{ item.username }}</td><td>{{ item.email }}</td>` instead of `<td>{{ result.getUsername }}</td><td>{{ result.getEmail }}</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Check $user with `instance`

```
if ($result instanceof User)
.......................................................................
```

I suggest you use `defined` in twig

```
{% if result is defined %}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    {% if error is defined %}
        <span class="error">{{ error }}</span>
    {% else %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th><th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            {% for item in result %}

              <tr>
                 <td>{{ result.getUsername }}</td><td>{{ result.getEmail }}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves one part of the issue. Now I get the twig rendered, but, apparently, the $result is always undefined.

Comment: Did you mean ($result instanceof User)?

Comment: instanceof is not a twig function.

Comment: Did I write for `twig`? ))

Answer (score 0):

In twig you assume that the result is an array. For this, uses findBy instead of findOneBy. findBy returns an array of objects with the desired search. The findOneBy return only an object with the desired search or null if results are not found.

Example:

```
// look for a single User by email
$result = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

// look for multiple User objects matching the email
$result = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(User::class)
                ->findBy(['email' => $email]);
```